# How to prevent malicious applications from pretending to be my application?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm creating a multi-tenant desktop application, which will access Azure and Microsoft online resources on behalf of the user.

Microsoft recommends using MSAL.NET authenticate the user, but to authenticate the user my application needs to pass-in the application-id.

```
// applicationId = {GUID of registered, multi-tenant app}
IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(applicationId)
        .Build();

// This prompts the user, asking for permission based on the scope 
// and application-id. 
AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();

// Now the application has a bearer token.
string bearToken = result.AccessToken;
```

Because this application-id is baked into the assembly, it's also easily extracted and so I have to assume it's public knowledge.

Given this how do I prevent malicious applications and assemblies from pretending to be my registered application?  Is this even possible to prevent within the pure desktop space?

Comment: The Application Id isn't a secret perse, your users are still logging in no?.

Comment: @TheGeneral The users are logging in using their own Microsoft credentials.  These aren't internal users but school; home; or corporate users.

Comment: Asking my question another way:  How can the user be sure that when they're prompted to enter credentials via MSAL.NET, that the application and calling assembly is actually published by me?

Comment: There are several layers of concerns here, the main is you have no control over the users environment. You cant stop the user downloading malware, or determine if your user is a malicious actor, you don't even have control over whether a user has been coerced into a log in. All you can do is sign your app (which is far from fool proof), and usethe least-privilege principle on your remote resources. Its like asking how a banking page assures its users aren't phished, or hackers. At the extreme, You cant

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate to admit it, I have to concede that there's no foolproof way to prevent access and the best that can be done are to:

- To strong-sign the desktop application (a given).
- Restrict the capabilities of the registered application and its APIs.

Even if this were all done on the browser, the same problem applies as we're relying on the client's browser installation and extensions being malware free.

Comment: Think of the id GUID as more of a special name than a secret. I know your name is John. That doesn't mean I have everything I need (or even very much of what I need) to impersonate your identity. All this is doing is presenting a formal, unique name to be **sure** they're talking about the right application.